# ¿Por qué en SSH reconoce una versión de PHP y en web reconoce otra?

Tags: php, ubuntu, php5, apache2, ssh

Tengo 2 versiones de `php` en mi servidor.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que me está sucediendo es que en la consola cuando le doy `php -v` me reconoce la más alta.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero en la web me reconoce la más baja `php 5.5.9`, que es con la que me quiero quedar.

Ya eliminé la otra versión que no quiero, que sería la `5.6.30`, y aún así me sigue reconociendo esta versión.

Utilicé los siguientes comandos con la intención de forzarlo.

```
sudo apt-get purge php5.6.30
sudo apt-get remove php5.6.30
sudo apt-get clean php5.6.30
rm -rf php/
```

Comment: Podrías intentar con Synaptic http://www.nongnu.org/synaptic/ es un auxiliar gráfico para la instalación y des instalación de paquetes para sistemas basados en Debian.

Comment: relacionado https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151943/81450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tenía un problema similar, pero con las versiones 5.5 y 5.6 con *Ubuntu Server 14*.

> Por si acaso quieres probarlo, recomiendo hacer copia de seguridad (o `snapshot` si es una máquina virtual) para poder revertir los cambios en caso de que no te funcione y no hacerlo en un sistema en producción sin probarlo antes en un sistema de desarrollo.

Primero ver la versión instalada o con que comandos se instaló, por ejemplo:

Si se instaló la versión 5.6, en mi caso fue mediante `sudo apt-get install php5.6`.

O la versión 5.5 `sudo apt-get install php5`.

Esta definición usada para la instalación (`php5`, `php5.6`), se utilizará para desactivar y activar el módulo *PHP* de *Apache* mediante:

```
sudo a2dismod php5 ; sudo a2enmod php5.6 ; sudo service apache2 restart
```

... y para la *CLI* usaremos:

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php5.6
```

Cambiando las definiciones, podemos alternar entre las distintas versiones de *PHP* instaladas si necesitamos desarrollar en diferentes entornos.

Comment: Perfecto brother muchísimas gracias me funciono de maravilla.

Comment: @user3566703 Me alegro. Puedes usar estos comandos teniendo varias versiones de `php` instaladas e ir cambiando entre ellas según necesites.