# Versiones de PHP diferentes en Servidor

Tags: php

consulto el siguiente problema: tengo un servidor apache manejado por plesk. A un dominio le modifique la versionde php a 7.2.3 y me figura así en plesk y también cuando ingreso un archivo php que muestra phpinfo(), hasta ahí todo ok. Pero si ingreso a dicho dominio por consola ssh y pido la version de php, con php -v me indica la 7.0.28. Si trato de instalar un laravel, me toma la version vieja de php, como que la nueva no esta instalada. Alguien tuvo esta diferencia de versionado? Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: ¿Qué gnu/linux usas? Si es debian, "update-alternatives --config php" o puedes usar el enlace directo a la versión que quieres: "php7.0 -v" o "php5.6 -v" por ejemplo

Comment: es un ubuntu 16.

Comment: Está basada en debian, busca algo específico para ubuntu, pero creo que funcionará.

Comment: Bueno, verifique con update-alternatives --config php, en ubuntu, y me indico que solo esta instalada la version 7.0, pero no entiendo bien el tema, porque en plesk tengo dominios corriendo con 5.6  Como que plesk me indica una cosa y la terminal, otra, ese el el tema.

Comment: voy a revisar un poco mas, gracias.

Comment: Aquí tienes la ayuda oficial de plesk: https://docs.plesk.com/en-US/onyx/administrator-guide/web-hosting/php-management/installing-php.75153/ creo que en un cápitulo he visto algo al respecto, suerte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
phpinfo();
```

te dará la versión web del php

```
php -v
```

te dará la version CLI (interfaz de linea de comandos) del php

dependiendo del webserver q uses (los mas comunes son apache y nginx) cambia la forma de cargar el módulo o version de php para la web. Esto es lo que permite tener varias versiones de php corriendo a la vez.

Para cambiar sólo la versión CLI:

```
echo "* Switching CLI PHP to 7.2..."
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2 > /dev/null
```

tomado de https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-switch-scripts/blob/master/switch-to-php-7.2.sh

Si queres cambiar globalmente ambas versiones (apache y cli) puedes bajarte e instalar el script de ese repo (https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-switch-scripts)

del mismo repo para instalar php 7.2:

```
echo "* Installing PHP 7.2..."
sudo apt-get install -y php7.2 php7.2-common php7.2-cli > /dev/null

echo "* Installing PHP 7.2 extensions..."
sudo apt-get install -y php7.2-bz2 php7.2-curl php7.2-gd php7.2-json php7.2-mbstring php7.2-mysql php7.2-opcache php7.2-readline php7.2-soap php7.2-sqlite3 php7.2-tidy php7.2-xml php7.2-xsl php7.2-zip php-redis > /dev/null

echo "* Installing additional PHP extensions..."
sudo apt-get install -y php-memcache php-memcached  > /dev/null
```

https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-switch-scripts/blob/master/setup.sh

Comment: añadido el ejemplo para cambiar sólo CLI y enlace a utilidad para cambiar apache y cli