# ¿Como cambiar la versión de PHP para CLI en Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: php, ubuntu, composer, lumen

Esto debería ser fácil, pero no lo es.

He instalado la versión 7.1.20 y la versión 7.2 de PHP en mi sistema operativo Ubuntu 16.04. Estoy seguro que lo hice bien, ya que al ejecutar en consola

```
update-alternatives --list php
```

Obtengo la siguiente lista

```
/usr/bin/php7.0
/usr/bin/php7.1
/usr/bin/php7.2
```

Entiendo que para cambiar la versión de PHP que se ejecuta en la lista de comandos, he de ejecutar el comando

```
sudo update-alternatives --set php /usr/bin/php7.2
```

Use este otro comando, `update-alternatives --display php` para verificar el resultado, y esto fue lo que me mostro la terminal

```
php - manual mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/php7.2
  link currently points to /usr/bin/php7.2
  link php is /usr/bin/php
  slave php.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz
/usr/bin/php7.0 - priority 70
  slave php.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/php7.0.1.gz
/usr/bin/php7.1 - priority 71
  slave php.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/php7.1.1.gz
/usr/bin/php7.2 - priority 72
  slave php.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/php7.2.1.gz
```

Como ven, el link a php esta mal. Y se puede comprobar. Cuando deseo revisar que versión de PHP tengo en consola, usando el comando `php -v`, obtengo el siguiente resultado

```
PHP 7.1.1 (cli) (built: Feb  1 2017 01:39:46) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2017 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.1.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2017 Zend Technologies
```

Intente primeramente actualizar el symlink de php usando `sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/php7.2 php`, pero no funciono. Despues intente borrar el link con `unlink php` y crear uno nuevo con `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/php7.2 php`, pero nada.

La razón que necesito cambiar de versión de PHP, es porque quiero usar Lumen (versión pequeña de Laravel) para un proyecto web. Entonces, el problema viene al crear un nuevo proyecto en Lumen. Al ejecutar

```
lumen new proyecto1
```

Los archivos se crean, pero obtengo decenas de errores, empezando por el siguiente, todo a causa de la versión de PHP:

```
  Problem 1
    - This package requires php >=7.1.3 but your PHP version (7.1.1) does not satisfy that requirement.
...
```

Entonces, la pregunta es, ¿Qué me hace falta por hacer para cambiar correctamente la versión de PHP en mi sistema operativo?

Comment: fijate el script de https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151943/81450  
   (https://github.com/rapidwebltd/php-switch-scripts)

Comment: @aloMalbarez Gracias. Todo eso ya lo intente, como puse en mi pregunta y al hacer `php -v` sigo obteniendo que tengo la version 7.1.1 de PHP CLI, no tengo idea de porque. Si tuvieras alguna otra idea, bienvenida sea.

Comment: probaste el script completo? setea los repo y baja lo que haga falta luego cada shell script configura todo automágicamente (lo uso habitualmente donde tenga que hacer un deploy con varias versiones) si no funciona habria que probar desinstalar todos los php (limpiar cache de apt) y volver a instalarlos desde el repo `ppa:ondrej/php` como en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/157211/81450

Comment: `$ which php` apunta al `/usr/bin/php` ?

Comment: `$ type php` -> `php is /usr/bin/php`  también te puede llegar a decir si es un alias

Comment: @aloMalbarez, si, como puse mas arriba,`php` creo si es un alias de `/usr/bin/php` y creo que eso es lo que esta dando problemas. Bueno, la verdad es que el resultado de `type php` es `php is hashed (/usr/bin/php)` y obviamente no soy un experto en eso, pero creo que eso significa que si es un alias. Tenes alguna idea de como cambiar eso?

Comment: si `$ /usr/bin/php -v` da la versión correcta puede que necesites editar el `composer.lock` que genera lumen https://stackoverflow.com/a/46786305/1423096

Comment: lo cual me lleva a... será que el composer está desactualizado?

Comment: @aloMalbarez en efecto, `/usr/bin/php -v` da la version correcta y la que necesito. Voy a ver la pregunta que enlazaste para ver si lo puedo solucionar. Me parece que voy a poder hacerlo.

Comment: @aloMalbarez lo primero que hice al querer empezar este proyecto con Lumen fue actualizar Composer. Pero en ese momento no habia actualizado la version de PHP, quizas alli este el asunto. Lo probare tambien.

Comment: @aloMalbarez no funciono. Incluso hasta reinstale Composer, siguiendo los consejos del ultimo link. Creo que el verdadero problema esta en que `php` apunta a `/usr/bin/php`. O no se...

Comment: quedaría verificar si `lumen new ` es lo que falla dale directamente con composer onda: `composer create-project laravel/lumen proyecto1 --prefer-dist`

Comment: @aloMalbarez funciono creando el proyecto directamente con Composer. Muchas gracias por la ayuda, aunque realmente me gustaria saber que esta pasando. Se me hace todo muy raro.